# Monotonic, surjective function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have tried to answer the following question from my textbook:

Suppose the following function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$, $c<d$. The function is monotonically increasing and surjective.

a) Proof that f(a)=c and f(b)=d

b) Proof that f is continuous
(Note: later on we will prove that from (a) and (b) follows that f is surjective)

c) Show that the inverse function of f exists and that it is continuous on [c,d]

What I did up until now:

a)
Suppose $f(a)\neq c$ Then $f(a)>c$ because the function is monotonic. Thus there exists a $x \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x)=c$ and $x \neq a$. Thus $f(x)<f(a)$ and thus, because $f$ is monotonically increasing, $x<a$. But then $ x \notin [a,b]$ which is a contradiction.

Proving that $f(b)=d$ goes similarly

b) My teacher showed the following proof, which I don't completly understand.

Choose $x_{1,2}=f^{-1}(f(x)\pm \epsilon)$ (exists because $f$ is surjective)
We know that $x_1 \leq x \leq x_2$. Choose $\delta:=\frac{1}{2}Min(x-x_1,x_2-x)$.
Take $y \in B(x;\delta)$ then $x_1 < y <x_2$ Thus $f(x_1)<f(y)<f(x_2)$, thus $f(x) \in B(f(x),\epsilon)$.

I would like if people could help me by checking my answer with question a and explain why the answer for b is correct. I don't understand how we know that we can take the inverse function of $f$. Could someone explain to me why this is true. I don't know how to write down an answer for question c, it seems logical but I can't explain it.

Comment: (a) not correct: assume $f(a) \ne c$. Then f(a) > c as f is surjective onto [c, d]. Then if $x \in [a, b], x\ne a$, $f(x) > f(a) > c$ by monotonicity.  Then for all $y \in [c, f(a) )$, there is, by monotonicity again, no $x \in [a, b]$ st $f(x) = y$. Contradiction. Your argument is flawed at a couple of steps.

Comment: Why isn't monotonicity the reason for $f(a)>c$. Cause I thought that because c is the smallest element of the set, any other element not equal to c should be larger. Thus $f(a)>c$. I now also see I made a mistake $x \neq c$ has been changed to $x \neq a$

Comment: if $f(a) \ne c$, then - from monotonicity alone - you cannot deduce anything for $x \ne a$ from that fact alone.

Comment: BUt we know that $a$ is mapped to an element in $[c,d]$ and $c$ is the smallest element of this interval. Thus I figured that if $f(a) \neq c$ then $f(a)>c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Actually, if $f(a)\neq c$, then $f(a)>c$ simply because the counterdomain of $f$ is $[c,b]$, not because $f$ is monotonic. Also, there is no need for $x\neq c$. You're correct in implying that $f(x)<f(a)$ and thus $x<a$, which is a contradiction.

b) I'm going to do some more details: Let $x\in[a,b]$. For simplicity, suppose that $x\neq a$, $x\neq b$ (otherwise, you have to check only left or right continuity, which is very similar to this case). Let $\varepsilon>0$, and consider $\varepsilon'=\frac{1}{2}\min(d-f(x),f(x)-c,\varepsilon)$ (notice that $\varepsilon'$ depends only on $\varepsilon$), so that $\varepsilon'>0$ and the interval $(f(x)-\varepsilon',f(x)+\varepsilon')$ is contained in $(c,d)$. By surjectivity, there exists $x_{\varepsilon}^-,x_{\varepsilon}^+\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x_{\varepsilon}^\pm)=f(x)\pm\varepsilon'$. Since $f$ is monotonic, then $x_{\varepsilon}^-<x<x_{\varepsilon}^+$.

Let $\delta=\frac{1}{2}\min(x_{\varepsilon}^+-x,x-x_{\varepsilon}^-)$ (notice that $\delta$ depends solely on $\varepsilon$). Given any $y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, we have $x_{\varepsilon}^-<x-\delta<y<x+\delta<x_{\varepsilon}^+$, so, since $f$ is monotonic,
$$f(x)-\varepsilon<f(x)-\varepsilon'=f(x_\varepsilon^-)<f(y)<f(x_\varepsilon^+)=f(x)+\varepsilon'<f(x)+\varepsilon$$
because $\varepsilon'<\varepsilon$. Thus, we have just shown that $f(y)\in(f(x)-\varepsilon,f(x)+\varepsilon)$ whenever $y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, so $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Since $x$ was arbitrary (and assuming you have already shown the cases $x=a$ and $x=b$), then $f$ is continuous.

c)By assumption, $f$ is surjective and, since $f$ is monotonic, it is injective, so there exists an inverse $f^{-1}$. This inverse is also surjective and, you can easily check, monotonic. By item b), with $f^{-1}$ in place of $f$, $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: I've learned that you always need to specify $\delta$ if you want to show a limit exists and that you can't put any restrictions on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Since we're looking for small, $\varepsilon$, we can always assume that $\varepsilon$ is "not very big". About the $\delta$, there are some equivalences for continuity which I wasn't sure you knew or not. I've edited it to fit your needs.