# Show that the real valued identity function is continuous

Tags: analysis

How do I show with the definition of continuity that $f : \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{ R}$ defined by $f(x)= x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is continuous?

I understand that this function is continuous, however I am having a hard time proving it. Especially because we have been using converging sequences to prove the continuity of functions and I am not sure if the book wants met to do that here as well.

If so I think it would be something like this:

> Pick an $(x_k)_{k∈\mathbb{N}}$ in $A$ that converges to $a$.
>
> Pick an $ε > 0$ , then we can find an $δ > 0$ such that $||f(x)-f(a)|| < ε$ for all $x ∈ A$ with $||x-a|| < δ$.
>
> Because $(x_k))_{k∈\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$. We can find an $k_0 ∈ \mathbb{N}$ such that $||x_k-a|| < δ$ for all $k\ge k_0$. Pick a $k\ge k_0$ then $||f(x_k)-f(a)|| < ε$ and thus $(f(x_k))_{k ∈ \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f(a)$.

Would this be correct. Maybe someone could show me how to prove this without using converging sequences.

Comment: What does "f : R -> R : x -> x" mean? Do you mean that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes, sorry that is how my book states it. But that is indeed what it means

Comment: If $x_k$ converges to $a$, then $f(x_k) = x_k$ converges to $f(a)$, which is $a$. So we are done. Which part of this proof is troublesome?

Comment: If you want a proof which doesn't use sequential criteria, then observe that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta(=\varepsilon)>0$ such that $|x-a|<\varepsilon\implies |f(x)-f(a)| (=|x-a|)<\delta(=\varepsilon)$.

Comment: The proof that you proposed in the question is a mixture of a proof using an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument and another proof using convergent sequences. The mixture looks pretty confusing to me; either of the proofs that it mixes would be nice and simple (as indicated in the other comments).

Answer (score 4):

Let $f$ be the identity function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Here are six weird reasons why $f$ is continuous (number 2 will make you cry, then number 3 will restore your faith in humanity!)

- The identity trivially satisfies that the preimage of any open set is open.
- For every $\epsilon$, pick $\delta = \epsilon$. Then $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. So the identity is in fact *uniformly* continuous.
- $f$ is differentiable: its derivative is $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x+h-x}{h} = 1$. Therefore it is continuous.
- If $(x_n) \to x$, then $(f(x_n)) = (x_n) \to x = f(x)$, so $f$ preserves the convergence of sequences.
- Consider the natural hyperreal extension which I will write $\bar{f}$ because my MathJax-foo is not good enough and I don't have access to \prescript. Then if $dx$ is infinitesimal, we have $\bar{f}(x+dx) - \bar{f}(x) = x + dx - x = dx$, which is infinitesimal.
- $f$ is [monotone and surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821754/monotonic-surjective-function). (OK, I don't know of a way of proving this that doesn't basically boil down to the epsilon-delta of method 2. But it's nice to know.)